# ISR execution in a non-preemptive system

Tags: operating-system, embedded, rtos

in a non preemptive system, after an ISR finishes execution, will the interrupted task continue execution even if a higher priority task was activated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have made a statement rather than asking a question (adding a ? at the end does not really make it a question; just grammatically confused ).  What makes you think that might be true?

Comment: @Clifford I am sorry for that I copied the statement of the question which its answer was either the statement is true or false. I edited the question now

Comment: The answer may be RTOS specific. Is there a specific RTOS in your mind? FreeRTOS maybe?

Comment: @Tagli but FreeRTOS (and RTOS in general) is pre-emptive, so presumably not that.

Comment: Presumably this refers to cooperative multitasking, where a task must explicitly yield for a scheduling decision to be made.   Draw your on conclusion.

Comment: @Clifford , FreeRTOS is pre-emptive by default, but it can also be configured to be **non** pre-emptive.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to FreeRTOS, and may not be relevant to other RTOS'es.

FreeRTOS is preemptive by default. However, it can also be configured to be non-preemptive by the config option in *FreeRTOSConfig.h*

```
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION 0
```

Normally, a return from ISR does not trigger a context switch. But in preemptive systems it's often desirable, so in most FreeRTOS examples, you see `portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);` at the end of the ISR, which triggers a context switch if `xHigherPriorityTaskWoken` is `pdTRUE`.

`xHigherPriorityTaskWoken` is initialized to `pdFALSE` at the start of the ISR (manually by the user), and operations which can cause a context switch, such as `vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR()` , `xQueueSendToBackFromISR()` etc. , take it as an argument and set it to `pdTRUE` if a context switch is required after the system call.

In a non-preemptive configuration, you simply pass `NULL` to such system calls instead of `xHigherPriorityTaskWoken`, and do **not** call `portYIELD_FROM_ISR()` at the end of the ISR. In this case, even if a higher priority task is awakened by the ISR, execution returns to the currently running task and remains there until this task yields or makes a blocking system call.

You may mix ISR yield mechanism with preemption method. For example, you can force a context switch (preemption) from ISR even when `configUSE_PREEMPTION` is 0, but this may cause problems if the interrupted/preempted task doesn't expect it to happen, so I don't recommend it.